# Get response from EWS behind proxy

Tags: proxy, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, exchangewebservices

I have ASP.NET Core application on server behind proxy.

In this app i call EWS to get EmailDetails. Is there any solution to set proxy for this request?

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them. Also please don't stuff keywords into the title, use the tags section for it

Comment: Sorry, i'll keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
var wp = new WebProxy("url")
{
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password"),
  BypassProxyOnLocal = true
}
```

And

```
 _exchangeService.WebProxy = wp;
```